# Cloudkit subscription error: BAD_REQUEST (just production mode)

Tags: xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I make an App with Cloudkit subscription. (see this code).
I tested developer mode, and work fine.
I publish my App, and that is not working :(
I get the following error message (Cloudkit Dashboard Log)
error: BAD_REQUEST
operation: subscription modify
database: private
zone: _zoneWide

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
    let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "recordDT",
                                           predicate: predicate,
                                           subscriptionID: subscriptionID,
                                           options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordDeletion, .firesOnRecordUpdate])
    let notification = CKNotificationInfo()
    notification.alertBody = "change cloudkit"
    notification.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    subscription.notificationInfo = notification
    publicDB.save(subscription) { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } 
    }
```

I found this log:
[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Found the root cause of the error :)

I saw this the icloudkit dashboard webpage "Subscription types are automatically created when your app creates a Query Subscription." 
This work fine the developer pages, but not true the production page :(

Must be use "deploy to production" function, after the subscripttion was created

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Worked fine on dev but failed on production. The cause was my production database had not been updated with schema changes that had been made to the dev database. CloudKit automatically changes the schema of the developer databases, but you must push those changes into production. (Which is by design and a very good design choice at that.) So, if you are still having the problem, go to CloudKit dashboard and publish your changes from the developer version of your database into production.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your code for how you define `publicDB` and `subscriptionID`?

You might try saving the subscription using a `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` instead of a `save` and see if it makes a difference.

```
let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)

operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { saved, deleted, error in
  if let error = error{
    print(error)
  }else{
    print("Subscriptions saved: \(saved)\nSubscriptions deleted: \(deleted)")
  }
}

publicDB.add(operation)
```

Comment: Hello, there is:
        container = CKContainer.default()
        publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
        privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
        let subscriptionID = "cloudkit-recordType-changes"

Comment: I just saw the screenshot of your log. That error doesn't seem like it's coming from your subscription. Can you clear your log and execute just the `CKQuerySubscription` save and see if the error appears?

Comment: every privateDB or publicDB save (subscription) call is the same error.
But on the developer system, all are successful.
Perhaps this subscriptioID is wrong? (cloudkit-recordType-changes)

Comment: Yeah, you might try a subscription ID that doesn't have `-` in it, but that doesn't explain why it would work on dev and not on prod.

Comment: I agree
The problem is that it is not possible to debug the prod application :(